# weird behaviour with addChild

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

i am trying to add one Box to my application using the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                >
    <mx:HBox height="100%" width="100%" backgroundColor="red"  borderColor="black"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.containers.Box;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            protected function button1_clickHandler():void
            {
                var box:Box = new Box();
                box.setStyle("backgroundColor","blue");
                box.height = 100;
                box.width = 100;
                //box.addChild(new Button());
                addChild(box);
                trace("children  "+numChildren);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button label="click" click="button1_clickHandler()" x="200" y="200" />
</mx:Application>
```

this code is work in flexBuilder.but it doesn't work while compiling in command prompt(using mxmlc command).
please suggest me on this issue, because my work is fully depending on command prompt.

thanks in advance
vengatesh s

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the compiler you are using. If you are using the Flex 4+ compiler I would suggest you to try using addElement instead of addChild. The same code above just changes to

```
protected function button1_clickHandler():void
{
    var box:Box = new Box();
    box.setStyle("backgroundColor","blue");
    box.height = 100;
    box.width = 100;
    /********** ----------- CHANGE----------------------********/
    // This is the only change from your code
    addElement(box);
    /********** ----------- CHANGE----------------------********/
    trace("children  "+numChildren);
}
```

Comment: here i don't use the Flex4+ compiler, i just use the Flex3.3 SDK.

Comment: It seems like you are starting a new project! Is there a specific reason you are using an older Flex version?

Comment: this is sample snippet only. i have to do some modification in my older project which is so huge.So i need it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error the mxmlc compiler is giving you? It would be good to know the exact error. Are you saying that this application code ( the same one as above doesnt get compiled ? ) Or is it your larger application which doesnt get compiled? Can you paste the compiler error here?